# RGB to XYZ and LAB colours conversion

Tags: javascript, rgb

I'm having problems converting colours from RGB to LAB space
It should be straight forward using the formulas from [here](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH), only I'm getting back the wrong values

- RGB = 56,79,132
- X = 8.592
- Y = 8.099
- Z = 22.940

and CIE-L*ab as

- L*  34.188
- a*  8.072
- b* -32.478

This is my code; but I can't see where I'm going wrong. It maybe due to floating points like this [fella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629798/whats-wrong-with-this-rgb-to-xyz-color-space-conversion-algorithm) before me. Thank you.

```
// user colour
var Red   = 56;
var Green = 79;
var Blue  = 132;

// user colour converted to XYZ space
XYZ = RGBtoXYZ(Red,Green,Blue)
var colX = XYZ[0];
var colY = XYZ[1];
var colZ = XYZ[2];

// alert(XYZ)

LAB = XYZtoLAB(colX, colY, colZ)

alert(LAB)

function RGBtoXYZ(R, G, B)
{
    var_R = parseFloat( R / 255 )        //R from 0 to 255
    var_G = parseFloat( G / 255 )        //G from 0 to 255
    var_B = parseFloat( B / 255 )        //B from 0 to 255

    if ( var_R > 0.04045 ) var_R = ( ( var_R + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ^ 2.4
    else                   var_R = var_R / 12.92
    if ( var_G > 0.04045 ) var_G = ( ( var_G + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ^ 2.4
    else                   var_G = var_G / 12.92
    if ( var_B > 0.04045 ) var_B = ( ( var_B + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ^ 2.4
    else                   var_B = var_B / 12.92

    var_R = var_R * 100
    var_G = var_G * 100
    var_B = var_B * 100

    //Observer. = 2°, Illuminant = D65
    X = var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805
    Y = var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722
    Z = var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505
    return [X, Y, Z]
}


function XYZtoLAB(x, y, z)
{
    var ref_X =  95.047;
    var ref_Y = 100.000;
    var ref_Z = 108.883;

    var_X = x / ref_X          //ref_X =  95.047   Observer= 2°, Illuminant= D65
    var_Y = y / ref_Y          //ref_Y = 100.000
    var_Z = z / ref_Z          //ref_Z = 108.883

    if ( var_X > 0.008856 ) var_X = var_X ^ ( 1/3 )
    else                    var_X = ( 7.787 * var_X ) + ( 16 / 116 )
    if ( var_Y > 0.008856 ) var_Y = var_Y ^ ( 1/3 )
    else                    var_Y = ( 7.787 * var_Y ) + ( 16 / 116 )
    if ( var_Z > 0.008856 ) var_Z = var_Z ^ ( 1/3 )
    else                    var_Z = ( 7.787 * var_Z ) + ( 16 / 116 )

    CIE_L = ( 116 * var_Y ) - 16
    CIE_a = 500 * ( var_X - var_Y )
    CIE_b = 200 * ( var_Y - var_Z )

return [CIE_L, CIE_a, CIE_b]
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `^` is bitwise xor in javascript not a power operator. I think `Math.pow` is what you are looking for.

Comment: or **, eg `4**2 = 16`

Answer (score 7):

```js
/**
 * Converts RGB color to CIE 1931 XYZ color space.
 * https://www.image-engineering.de/library/technotes/958-how-to-convert-between-srgb-and-ciexyz
 * @param  {string} hex
 * @return {number[]}
 */
export function rgbToXyz(hex) {
    const [r, g, b] = hexToRgb(hex).map(_ => _ / 255).map(sRGBtoLinearRGB)
    const X =  0.4124 * r + 0.3576 * g + 0.1805 * b
    const Y =  0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
    const Z =  0.0193 * r + 0.1192 * g + 0.9505 * b
    // For some reason, X, Y and Z are multiplied by 100.
    return [X, Y, Z].map(_ => _ * 100)
}

/**
 * Undoes gamma-correction from an RGB-encoded color.
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color
 * @param  {number}
 * @return {number}
 */
function sRGBtoLinearRGB(color) {
    // Send this function a decimal sRGB gamma encoded color value
    // between 0.0 and 1.0, and it returns a linearized value.
    if (color <= 0.04045) {
        return color / 12.92
    } else {
        return Math.pow((color + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
    }
}

/**
 * Converts hex color to RGB.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb
 * @param  {string} hex
 * @return {number[]} [rgb]
 */
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    const match = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex)
    if (match) {
        match.shift()
        return match.map(_ => parseInt(_, 16))
    }
}

/**
 * Converts CIE 1931 XYZ colors to CIE L*a*b*.
 * The conversion formula comes from <http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php>.
 * https://github.com/cangoektas/xyz-to-lab/blob/master/src/index.js
 * @param   {number[]} color The CIE 1931 XYZ color to convert which refers to
 *                           the D65/2° standard illuminant.
 * @returns {number[]}       The color in the CIE L*a*b* color space.
 */
// X, Y, Z of a "D65" light source.
// "D65" is a standard 6500K Daylight light source.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminant_D65
const D65 = [95.047, 100, 108.883]
export function xyzToLab([x, y, z]) {
  [x, y, z] = [x, y, z].map((v, i) => {
    v = v / D65[i]
    return v > 0.008856 ? Math.pow(v, 1 / 3) : v * 7.787 + 16 / 116
  })
  const l = 116 * y - 16
  const a = 500 * (x - y)
  const b = 200 * (y - z)
  return [l, a, b]
}

/**
 * Converts Lab color space to Luminance-Chroma-Hue color space.
 * http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_Lab_to_LCH.html
 * @param  {number[]}
 * @return {number[]}
 */
export function labToLch([l, a, b]) {
    const c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
    const h = abToHue(a, b)
    return [l, c, h]
}

/**
 * Converts a and b of Lab color space to Hue of LCH color space.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733379/conversion-of-cielab-to-cielchab-not-yielding-correct-result
 * @param  {number} a
 * @param  {number} b
 * @return {number}
 */
function abToHue(a, b) {
    if (a >= 0 && b === 0) {
        return 0
    }
    if (a < 0 && b === 0) {
        return 180
    }
    if (a === 0 && b > 0) {
        return 90
    }
    if (a === 0 && b < 0) {
        return 270
    }
    let xBias
    if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        xBias = 0
    } else if (a < 0) {
        xBias = 180
    } else if (a > 0 && b < 0) {
        xBias = 360
    }
    return radiansToDegrees(Math.atan(b / a)) + xBias
}

function radiansToDegrees(radians) {
    return radians * (180 / Math.PI)
}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180
}
```

Comment: "// For some reason, X, Y and Z are multiplied by 100." - yeah, probably the wrong place for that XYZ should be 0 to 1. Lab has luminance from 0 to 100, which is probably why they're doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some functions for RGB -> XYZ, XYZ -> LAB, LAB -> XYZ, XYZ -> RGB.

```js
function RGBtoXYZ([R, G, B]) {
    const [var_R, var_G, var_B] = [R, G, B]
        .map(x => x / 255)
        .map(x => x > 0.04045
            ? Math.pow(((x + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
            : x / 12.92)
        .map(x => x * 100)

    // Observer. = 2°, Illuminant = D65
    X = var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805
    Y = var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722
    Z = var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505
    return [X, Y, Z]
}

function XYZtoRGB([X, Y, Z]) {
    //X, Y and Z input refer to a D65/2° standard illuminant.
    //sR, sG and sB (standard RGB) output range = 0 ÷ 255

    let var_X = X / 100
    let var_Y = Y / 100
    let var_Z = Z / 100

    var_R = var_X *  3.2406 + var_Y * -1.5372 + var_Z * -0.4986
    var_G = var_X * -0.9689 + var_Y *  1.8758 + var_Z *  0.0415
    var_B = var_X *  0.0557 + var_Y * -0.2040 + var_Z *  1.0570

    return [var_R, var_G, var_B]
        .map(n => n > 0.0031308
            ? 1.055 * Math.pow(n, (1 / 2.4)) - 0.055
            : 12.92 * n)
        .map(n => n * 255)
}

const ref_X =  95.047;
const ref_Y = 100.000;
const ref_Z = 108.883;

function XYZtoLAB([x, y, z]) {
    const [ var_X, var_Y, var_Z ] = [ x / ref_X, y / ref_Y, z / ref_Z ]
        .map(a => a > 0.008856
            ? Math.pow(a, 1 / 3)
            : (7.787 * a) + (16 / 116))

    CIE_L = (116 * var_Y) - 16
    CIE_a = 500 * (var_X - var_Y)
    CIE_b = 200 * (var_Y - var_Z)

    return [CIE_L, CIE_a, CIE_b]
}

function LABtoXYZ([l, a, b]) {

    const var_Y = (l + 16) / 116
    const var_X = a / 500 + var_Y
    const var_Z = var_Y - b / 200

    const [X, Y, Z] = [var_X, var_Y, var_Z]
        .map(n => Math.pow(n, 3) > 0.008856
            ? Math.pow(n, 3)
            : (n - 16 / 116) / 7.787)

    return [X * ref_X, Y * ref_Y, Z * ref_Z]
}
```

Reference: http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php

Answer (score 0):

`function xyzc(c){return ((c/255)>0.04045)?Math.pow((((c/255)+0.055)/1.055),2.4)*100:(c/255)/12.92*100;}`

This line will convert a rgb channel to XYZ

Comment: No, it will not, also this is sRGB, not RGB (12.92 number). This just converts R'G'B' to linear RGB using sRGB curve. XYZ requires special matrix depending on what primaries that linear light (linear RGB) now is.